# Im not sure why im getting this result out of my pointers exercise

Tags: c, pointers, variables, printf

I've been asked to write what this codes does:

```
int main()
{
    int var1,var2, *ptr;
    ptr=&var1;
    var2=12;
    *ptr=var2;
    var1=var1/ *ptr;
    printf("%d %d", var1,var2);
}
```

Now my question is what does this means. At first ptr stores the address of var1. Then var2 is defined as 12. the next step idk what it means and so with the last one. I finally i get printed 1 and 12. Not sure why.

What i understood is that 12 is stored in ptr aswell. So as ptr has var1 address, var1 gets a value of 12 too. and so the finall step would be var1=12/12. And thats why i get 1 and 12 in my printf. This is just what i understood but i dont really get it and im not sure if its correct. Btw ty for undesrtanding.

Comment: You need to read a textbook or tutorial, it will explain what all these mean. SO isn't a tutoring service, you're expected to learn the language basics.

Comment: `*ptr = var2;` means to store the value of `var2` in the place that `ptr` points to, which is `var1`. So this is the same as `var1  = var2;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `ptr=&var1;`

`&var1` is the address of the object `var1`. `ptr = &var1` stores the address in the object `ptr`.

> `var2 = 12;`

This stores 12 in the object `var2`.

> `*ptr = var2;`

This stores the value of `var2` in the object `*ptr`. Since 12 is stored in `var2`, it stores 12 in the object `*ptr`. Since the value of `ptr` is the address of `var1`, `*ptr` is `var1`. So `*ptr = var2` stores 12 in the object `var1`.

> `var1 = var1 / *ptr;`

`*ptr` is the object that `ptr` points to, which is `var1`. So `var1 / *ptr` divides the value of the numerator, `var1`, by the value of the denominator, `*ptr`, which is also `var1`. Both the numerator and the denominator have the value 12, so `var1 / *ptr` is 1. Then `var1 = var1 / *ptr` stores 1 in the object `var1`.

> `printf("%d %d", var1,var2);`

This prints the values of `var1` and `var2`, converted to decimal. Per the above, `var1` contains 1 and `var2` contains 12, so “1 12” is printed.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer `ptr` is initialized by the address of the variable `var1`.

```
ptr=&var1;
```

So using the expression `*ptr` is the same as using the expression `var1` because dereferencing the pointer you get the variable `var1`.

Thus these expression statements

```
*ptr=var2;
var1=var1/ *ptr;
```

may be equivalently rewritten like

```
var1 = var2;
var1 = var1 / var1;
```

`var2` was initially assigned with the integer constant `12`

```
var2=12;
```

and the result value of the variable `var1` will be equal to `1` independent on which value it has before assigning the result of the expression `var1 / var1` (of course provided that.`var1` was not equal to 0)